# Python flask apps on LightTPD (Windows) get [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: python, windows, sockets, lighttpd

I have a small Flask app that I am trying to get running on LightTPD web server. The app runs fine when I start it with Python. But when I try to make it run under LightTPD/fast_cgi, I get

"[Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"

every time I try to start the web server. Somewhere between the webserver and the app the permission of the executive changes.

My LightTPD vhost.confg part:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "test.localhost" {
  server.document-root = "c:/data/python/test"
  dir-listing.activate = "disable"
  accesslog.filename   = log_root + "/test.log"
  server.errorlog = log_root + "/test-error.log"
  fastcgi.server = (
    "/" => ((
        #"socket" => "c:\tmp\test-sock", # no file sockets in windows 
        "host" => "127.0.0.1",
        "port" => "12345",
        "bin-path" => "c:/data/python/test/test.fcgi",
        "check-local" => "disable",
        "max-procs" => 1,
        "fix-root-scriptname" => "enable"
    )),
  )
  alias.url = ( 
    "/static" => "c:/data/python/test/app/static"
  )
  url.rewrite-once = (
    "^(/static($|/.*))$" => "$1",
    "^(/.*)$" => "/test.fcgi$1"
  )
}
```

And my test app:

```
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
def test_app(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    yield 'Hello, world!\n'
WSGIServer(app, bindAddress=('127.0.0.1', 12345)).run()
```

I have run out of options to try. Disabled the firewall and anti-virus software, run LightTPD and Python.exe as administrator, but nothing seems to work. It worked for a brief moment, but I don't know if it was a fluke, or I changed some tiny detail somewhere. 
My next step will be to move this to a cgi. 
If this doesn't work, I'm going to try ngnix, or some other light httpd server.

Comment: 10013 points to a port issue. It might be blocked by a firewall or already in use.